# How to create/design data structures?

Tags: c++, networking, data-structures, struct, network-programming

I'm an intermediate hobby programmer who knows a fair bit of C++ and other programming languages, right now I am trying to work with raw sockets instead of cooked sockets in C++, but when im looking at samples and other people's source code (for learning purposes, not leeching) I can see that they all know how to make the headers for the network layers, for example they have written an ip header structure like this:

```
struct IP_HEADER
{
    BYTE  ver_ihl;        // Version (4 bits) and Internet Header Length (4 bits)
    BYTE  type;           // Type of Service (8 bits)
    WORD  length;         // Total size of packet (header + data)(16 bits)
    WORD  packet_id;      // (16 bits)
    WORD  flags_foff;     // Flags (3 bits) and Fragment Offset (13 bits)
    BYTE  time_to_live;   // (8 bits)
    BYTE  protocol;       // (8 bits)
    WORD  hdr_chksum;     // Header check sum (16 bits)
    DWORD source_ip;      // Source Address (32 bits)
    DWORD destination_ip; // Destination Address (32 bits)
 } IPHEADER;
```

but how do they know that they should use a BYTE on the version? I know it's the ip headers version which tells u wether its ipv4 or ipv6 etc.. but how do I know if I should use a BYTE or a WORD or any other variable?

to make things simple: I'm trying to understand how to make structures like the one above on my own for lets say another kind of header?

Comment: Usually there's some sort of specification that specifies what data items are where and how many bits/bytes they use.

Comment: In the above case it is a well defined standard.  Here is a Wiki pointer that specifically defines size and position of each element in an IPV4 header:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IP header structure is specified in RFC 791: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-11

The struct combines version (4bit) and ihl (4bit) in one BYTE (8bit) and Flags(3bit)/Fragmentation (13bit) in a WORD (16bit). All other parts are mapped one-to-one to BYTE (8bit), WORD(16bit) and DWORD(32bit).

Note: BYTE / WORD / DWORD are no C++ datatypes, this is probably defined somewhere in the code like this:

```
typedef unsigned char   BYTE; // 1byte
typedef unsigned short  WORD; // 2bytes
typedef unsigned long  DWORD; // 4bytes
```

Comment: so for things that are 4bits i should use BYTE ? and for things that are 8 i should use WORD ? O.o that does not make sense to me :L what about those that are 16 bits etc..

Comment: @Paze: Presumably, `BYTE` is 8 bits, `WORD` is 16, and `DWORD` is 32 (although you'll have to see the definitions to confirm, since these aren't standard types). The first byte contains two 4-bit values packed into one 8-bit variable.

Comment: Ahh okay now i see :) i always had a litlle thought that it might be like this, but i was really unsure, you have helped me out a lot, thank you and i hope more people might bennefit from this :) i think i will be able to make my own headers now and can continue my work with raw sockets ;)